# "configparser.DuplicateOptionError" when running AWS CLI command

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

When executing the following command in the mac terminal I got an error: `aws configure`

I couldn't really find anything helpful online and I am newbie to mac and to aws. Can somebody please help me fix it?
same thing would happen with other commands like `aws --version`
commands like `which aws`would work normally

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "botocore/configloader.py", line 149, in raw_config_parse
  File "configparser.py", line 696, in read
  File "configparser.py", line 1091, in _read
configparser.DuplicateOptionError: While reading from '/Users/sj-auteon/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: option 'aws_access_key_id' in section 'default' already exists

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws", line 27, in <module>
  File "aws", line 23, in main
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 90, in main
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 99, in create_clidriver
  File "botocore/session.py", line 361, in full_config
  File "botocore/configloader.py", line 152, in raw_config_parse
botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /Users/sj-auteon/.aws/credentials
[831] Failed to execute script aws```
````

Comment: Is your `./aws/credentials` file in the correct format?

Comment: I would say no, but I am not sure. Is there a way to reset the whole thing?

Comment: Just move or delete (if not important) the existing `credentials` file and create new one using `aws configure` command.

Comment: where can I find the file? or is there a command that would delete it from the terminal?

Comment: As in the error message, its in /Users/sj-auteon/.aws/credentials

Comment: I thought as much but I can not find the .aws there!! what could I have don wrong?

Comment: `.aws` is a hidden folder. To print out the content of the file `cat /Users/sj-auteon/.aws/credentials` to check what it has. To remove it (if not needed) `rm /Users/sj-auteon/.aws/credentials`

Comment: worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: No problem. I added the answer for future reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the comments. The solution was to delete existing `.aws/credentials` and create new one using `aws configure` command.

Comment: exactly! so easy yet so complicated when you are a beginner :)

Comment: Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.  thanks.