# How to clear gitlab aws Credentials?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, gitlab

So I'm working with gitlab with ansible and deploying it to an EC2 instance. There was some authentication issue on the pipeline so I changed my yaml file to authenticate always whenever I deploy.

It worked for a while, but now I encountered an issue saying "DuplicateSectionError" that describes an issue with AWS configuration because I've probably authenticated too much.

Here's the error log:

```
configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from '/root/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: section 'default' already existsDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 27, in <module>    sys.exit(main())  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 23, in main    return awscli.clidriver.main()  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 68, in main    driver = create_clidriver()  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 77, in create_clidriver    load_plugins(session.full_config.get('plugins', {}),  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 364, in full_config    cred_profiles = botocore.configloader.raw_config_parse(  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 151, in raw_config_parse    raise botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError(botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /root/.aws/credentialsTraceback (most recent call last):  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 149, in raw_config_parse    cp.read([path])  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 697, in read    self._read(fp, filename)  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 1067, in _read    raise DuplicateSectionError(sectname, fpname,configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from '/root/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: section 'default' already existsDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 27, in <module>    sys.exit(main())  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 23, in main    return awscli.clidriver.main()  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 68, in main    driver = create_clidriver()  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 77, in create_clidriver    load_plugins(session.full_config.get('plugins', {}),  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 364, in full_config    cred_profiles = botocore.configloader.raw_config_parse(  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 151, in raw_config_parse    raise botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError(botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /root/.aws/credentialsTraceback (most recent call last):  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 149, in raw_config_parse    cp.read([path])  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 697, in read    self._read(fp, filename)  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 1067, in _read    raise DuplicateSectionError(sectname, fpname,configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from '/root/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: section 'default' already existsDuring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:Traceback (most recent call last):  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 27, in <module>    sys.exit(main())  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 23, in main    return awscli.clidriver.main()  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 68, in main    driver = create_clidriver()  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 77, in create_clidriver    load_plugins(session.full_config.get('plugins', {}),  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 364, in full_config    cred_profiles = botocore.configloader.raw_config_parse(  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 151, in raw_config_parse    raise botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError(botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /root/.aws/credentialsError: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device", "stderr_lines": ["Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 149, in raw_config_parse", "    cp.read([path])", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 697, in read", "    self._read(fp, filename)", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 1067, in _read", "    raise DuplicateSectionError(sectname, fpname,", "configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from '/root/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: section 'default' already exists", "", "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:", "", "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 27, in <module>", "    sys.exit(main())", "  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 23, in main", "    return awscli.clidriver.main()", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 68, in main", "    driver = create_clidriver()", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 77, in create_clidriver", "    load_plugins(session.full_config.get('plugins', {}),", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 364, in full_config", "    cred_profiles = botocore.configloader.raw_config_parse(", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 151, in raw_config_parse", "    raise botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError(", "botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /root/.aws/credentials", "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 149, in raw_config_parse", "    cp.read([path])", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 697, in read", "    self._read(fp, filename)", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 1067, in _read", "    raise DuplicateSectionError(sectname, fpname,", "configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from '/root/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: section 'default' already exists", "", "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:", "", "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 27, in <module>", "    sys.exit(main())", "  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 23, in main", "    return awscli.clidriver.main()", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 68, in main", "    driver = create_clidriver()", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 77, in create_clidriver", "    load_plugins(session.full_config.get('plugins', {}),", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 364, in full_config", "    cred_profiles = botocore.configloader.raw_config_parse(", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 151, in raw_config_parse", "    raise botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError(", "botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /root/.aws/credentials", "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 149, in raw_config_parse", "    cp.read([path])", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 697, in read", "    self._read(fp, filename)", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3.8/configparser.py\", line 1067, in _read", "    raise DuplicateSectionError(sectname, fpname,", "configparser.DuplicateSectionError: While reading from '/root/.aws/credentials' [line  4]: section 'default' already exists", "", "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:", "", "Traceback (most recent call last):", "  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 27, in <module>", "    sys.exit(main())", "  File \"/usr/bin/aws\", line 23, in main", "    return awscli.clidriver.main()", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 68, in main", "    driver = create_clidriver()", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py\", line 77, in create_clidriver", "    load_plugins(session.full_config.get('plugins', {}),", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/session.py\", line 364, in full_config", "    cred_profiles = botocore.configloader.raw_config_parse(", "  File \"/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/botocore/configloader.py\", line 151, in raw_config_parse", "    raise botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError(", "botocore.exceptions.ConfigParseError: Unable to parse config file: /root/.aws/credentials", "Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I've found something close to my problem which is this:
["configparser.DuplicateOptionError" when running AWS CLI command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61479304/configparser-duplicateoptionerror-when-running-aws-cli-command)

So my question is, how do I clear wherever the authentication is happening from the bash script I've set for my gitlab? Is this the right way to do this or am I going about this on the wrong way?

Here's my gitlab yaml:

```
deploy:server:docker:
  stage: deploy
  image: registry.itsyndicate.org/public-area/ansible:2.10.4-py2.9.1-buster
  before_script:
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - ssh-add <(echo "$DEV_SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")
    - mkdir -p ~/.ssh && chmod 700 ~/.ssh
    - echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\tPort 22722\n\n" >> ~/.ssh/config
  script:
    - export API_SERVER=$(cat ./deploy.env | grep API_SERVER | awk -F= '{print $2}')
    - export ENVIRONMENT=$(cat ./deploy.env | grep ENVIRONMENT | awk -F= '{print $2}')
    - echo ${ENVIRONMENT}
    - echo Deploy on Server_IP - ${API_SERVER}
    - ansible-playbook -i ansible/inventory --limit ${ENVIRONMENT} --extra-vars "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID} AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY} ENVIRONMENT=${ENVIRONMENT} IMAGE_TAG=${CI_COMMIT_SHA}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} IMAGE_REGISTRY=${AWS_DOCKER_REGISTRY}" ansible/deploy.yml 
  dependencies:
    - prepare:envfiles:dev
    - build:server:docker
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH =~ /Feature-*/'
      when: manual
  cache: {}
```

Comment: Can you show your gitlab yaml configuration? Are you using gitlab.com shared runners, or your own private self-hosted runner? If using a self-hosted runner, [what executor](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/) are you using?

Comment: I'm using my own self-hosted runner. And I've added my gitlab yaml. For the executor I'm using shell